# Java Servlet 404 error

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

My system has Tomcat seven and all the files are under webapps. The file structure is

webapps/ WelcomeForm/ web/ WelcomeForm.html

WEB-INF/ web.xml

lib/ classes/ hello/ HelloWorldServlet.java HelloWorldServlet.class

The web folder holds WelcomeForm.html.

WEB-INF holds the web.xml.

lib holds servlet-api.jar and

classes holds HelloWorldServlet.java.

the html file runs fine but I cannot run the Java file as it returns the message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /hello

type Status report

message /hello

description The requested resource (/hello) is not available.
```

The code for the files is below:

WelcomeForm.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome Form</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
           <form method="POST" action="/hello">
        <font size="10" color="red">Hello World!</font><BR>

     Type your first name and click submit button <input TYPE=TEXT NAME="username" SIZE=20>
            <P><input type="submit" value="Submit">


       </form> 

    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>hello.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorldServlet.java

```java
package hello;

import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

      doPost(request,response);
      }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("username");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write("Your Name is :" );
    out.print(name);

  }    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing `servlet-api.jar` from your `lib` directory and change `action="/hello"` to `action="hello"`?

Comment: The API jar must be removed as Tomasz states, and if you're not generating the URL via JSTL you must make sure it is web-app-relative. Is the servlet file in /WEB-INF/classes, or /WEB-INF/lib/classes? It's unclear from your post because there's no real formatting. It must be in /WEB-INF/classes (under the package hierarchy).

Comment: Apparently, you had an error when deploying. Check the Tomcat server log files. It indicate when it starts deploying your web-app and why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check browser URL. You are missing context.

Let Say, You are running at http://localhost:8080/test/index.jsp where test is your context path.

So, When calling Servlet It should be like http://localhost:8080/test/hello.

In your case, Its not like that.

So, Adding cotextpath will solve your problem.

e.g. `action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/hello"`

OR you can use

e.g. `action="hello"`

So, When you add "/" to `action` always add context path.